# How to make Intellisense metadata persistent in Visual Studio Code

Tags: metadata, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio Code for C/C++ development (and I'm very happy with it).

However, I'm working on huge C/C++ projects, which makes Intellisense work for a long time before getting all the files, symbols, etc.

The problem is that the result of this long process seems to be non-persistent when I quit and come back to my project folder, Intellisense starts everything again, and this is not convenient to wait for 15 minutes before being able to go to a symbol definition.

Is it possible to force Intellisense parsed results to be persistent? Like allowing it to store metadata in .vscode directory of my project?

I think Intellisense stores everything in my home directory in a folder which must get cleaned periodically or when growing to a certain size (directory ~/.config/Code is 3 GB big so I guess it's there).

Alternatively can I increase the size limit of this folder?

Comment: Many times this is caused by an installed extension.

Comment: Vscode C++ extension does cache the data in database file.